# How to retain javascript array while page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**PHP file**

```
<input type="text" id="txtMyText">
<button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="addItemToArray()">Add to Array</button>
```

**Javascript file**

```
var myArray = []

function addItemToArray()
{
    myArray.push(document.getElementById("txtMyText").value);
}
```

Whenever I enter some value in a text field and hit the button, value gets stored in the array. When a page is refreshed, my array becomes empty. I want to retain its elements until I remove them manually. How do I retain them? Should I put array in PHP session or hidden field? If yes, then how?

Comment: Store it in a cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `localStorage` API for this purpose, Use `setItem()` method and do stringify the array before storing into the `localStorage`.
You can retrieve the stored item by `getItem()` and parse the stored array using `JSON.parse()`, something like

```
if(localStorage.getItem('textValues') == null){
    var myArray =[];
}else{
    myArray =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('textValues'));
   //-----------^parse the item by getting---^--stored item
}

function addItemToArray(){
    myArray.push(document.getElementById("txtMyText").value);
    localStorage.setItem('textValues', JSON.stringify(myArray));
    //------------^store the item by stringify--^
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ys2G5/2/)

Comment: Now, how can I store this javascript array in a PHP session as I have to use this info at other pages also?

Comment: You can the those stored item into other page in same way as defined at above code.

Comment: I meant you `You can get those stored item`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the browser's internal storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Store the array:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
```

Get the array from storage:

```
var items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("items"));
```

Comment: Only thing missing is a catch for the initial values

Comment: @Joe Frambach - I was also looking for initialization and checking for null values in sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1):

To retain it on refresh you are going to need to store in local storage. `localStorage.setItem("storageName", myArray)` then to retrieve it `localStorage.getItem("storageName")` or `var myArray = localStorage.getItem("storageName")`

Answer (score 1):

probably the easiest way would be using jQuery cookie

edit `var myArray = []`  /edit

```
if ($.cookie('arrayItems')){
      myArray=JSON.parse($.cookie('arrayItems'));
}


 function addItemToArray()  
 {
   myArray.push(document.getElementById("txtMyText").value);
  $.cookie('arrayItems',JSON.stringify(myArray));
 }
```

Comment: No indication in the question that jQuery is being used. Adding all of jQuery just to tweak a cookie seems inefficient. http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: @ceejayoz - I am using jQuery.

Comment: don't forget to put an else on that if to define the array otherwise you'll get an undefined error the first time.

Comment: @nkp `$.cookie` is probably not working because it's not actually part of jQuery. It's a plugin - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a PHP session, I would take advantage of AJAX. You'll need to create a file to handle the array as you create it. Here's a simple example.

**Your first page**

```
<?php 
    //start the PHP session to save your array in
    session_start(); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = [];
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['myArray'])) {
        foreach($_SESSION['myArray'] as $item){
            // prepopulate the session array from PHP
            echo "myArray[] = ".$item.";";
        }
    }
?>
function addItemToArray(){
    var addvalue = document.getElementById("txtMyText").value;
    myArray.push(addvalue);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }else {  var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)    {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText .", ";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","save_array.php?newValue="+,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="show_my_array">
    <?php
        //show array saved from last time
        if(isset($_SESSION['myArray'])) {
            foreach($_SESSION['myArray'] as $item){
                // prepopulate the session array from PHP
                echo $item.", ";
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
<input type="text" id="txtMyText">
<button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="addItemToArray()">Add to Array</button>
```

**save_array.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myArray'])){
    $_SESSION['myArray'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['myarray'][] = $_GET['newValue'];
echo $_GET['newValue'];
?>
```