# Local Storage setItem to store Images in an array and display using getItem

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a web application where I am trying to store different images, ( which are there across different pages, ) in an `ImageArray` which is a javascript array. I looked up the net and found that `LocalStorage API` in HTML5 is an effective way to do this, since the variables are preserved even after page reload.

My problem is I have an `ImageArray` in which I am storing my images by using the `saveImage()` function.

```
var ImageArray = new Array();   //declared as global variables
var i=0;     //declared as global variables


function saveImages(Image)

{
    if(ImageArray.length < 4)

       {           
        ImageArray[i] = new Image();
        ImageArray[i].src = Image;

        //alert('ImageArray:::'+ ImageArray);
        // ImageArray.push(Image);
        i=i+1;

        alert('Added For Comparison : ');
        alert('no_of_pics_added' + ImageArray.length);

        window.localStorage.setItem('ImageArray', JSON.stringify(ImageArray));
        //alert('ImageArray' +  JSON.stringify(ImageArray))
        }
        else
        {
        alert('You have already added 4 pics for comparison' + ImageArray.length);
        }
}
```

and this is the `displayImages()` function which is supposed to retrieve the saved images.

```
function displayImages()

{       
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('ImageArray') == null){
        alert('12124235246');
        var ImageArray =[];

    }
     else

    {    alert('98987987');
        ImageArray =  JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('ImageArray'));

    }

    ImageArray = new Array();   // initialising once the Images are displayed
    i=0;

}
```

The program goes into the else loop but nothing happens. I figure out from this that `window.localStorage.getItem` and the window.localStorage.setItem functions are the problem here. I have tried using both `window.localStorage.getItem`  and `localStorage.getItem`. I am using a browser which supports `HTML5` (chrome 37). 
I have been refering these links

[How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)
[How to retain javascript array while page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726080/how-to-retain-javascript-array-while-page-refresh)

Somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors on `JSON.stringify(ImageArray)`?

Comment: No..I tried to alert the stringified array.. it displays properly

Comment: Hm, right.

Any way, you can't stringify a `Image` object. you'll need to store an array of image src's, or something like that.

Comment: I actually have a canvas...which I am converting into an image using .toDataURL(). so what I get is the URL of the image which I am using, which is essentially a string

Comment: You are resetting the `ImageArray` object after you load the images...

Comment: thats right. @gavin ...This is because I want to be able to start afresh when I save the Images.